# Problem Background image dont show in Right-view

Tags: modeling

I have a Problem with the Background Images in the Right-view.

It only Shows in the camera-view.

Why? Please help me?

I Need it as a template for modelling in the TAB.

Comment: Hello :). Please provide some screenshots with your question. It's not very clear what you're asking. Without that, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Please add more information.